# nginx server won't start in MAMP on pc

Tags: nginx, localhost, mamp

I'm tried to using nginx on mamp, but it won't (apache is working)

Here is my setup screenshots: [image: mamp] [[image]][[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMJnc.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I just try and I had the same error. I have not able to completely figured out. But on the meantime I found this solution let me know if works for you.

First I installed Brew (http://brew.sh/index_es.html)

Copy paste on your terminal

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

When finishes running you can verify that its installed by

```
brew -v
```

Then install nginx with Brew

```
brew install nginx
```

When finishes running you can verify that its installed by

```
nginx -v
```

Now everything is supposed to be working. Now Couple of config. You go to the root folder of your machine and look for `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` open it with a text editor and you will have something like this:

(You just have to change two things the port and the url of your project)

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;


    server {
    listen       8080; #CHANGE TO 80
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;


    location / {
        root /Users/Mario/Sites/proyName; #URL of the project

    }
```

Don't change anything else.

After this just run

```
sudo nginx
```

If you need to stop running

```
sudo nginx -s stop
```

And the URL of your project should be http://localhost

Hope it helps on the meantime